# Ubuntu 18.04 running slow with 4GB RAM

Tags: memory-usage

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 4 GB Ram , NVIDIA GeForce 820M on a Lenovo Z50-70 laptop. My system is running quite slow in terms of GUI responsiveness when I try to use it after keeping it idle for around 7-8 hours. Opening tabs in the browser , using system setting etc become very slow and is also heating up too much (I can feel it). I used free -m and vmstat -S M 10 4 to check memory status. Following is the output for :

free -m

```
total          total       used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3841        2295         500         122        1044        1192
Swap:          8194        1462        6732
```

vmstat -S M 10 4 output

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0   1462    509     95    949    0    0    15    10   13   28  3  1 96  1  0
 0  0   1462    510     95    949    0    0     5    24  956 2384  4  2 94  0  0
 0  0   1462    514     95    949    0    0     2     6  815 3509  7  2 91  0  0
 0  0   1462    513     95    949    0    0     2    28 1119 3586  9  2 88  1  0
```

From the outputs , it is visible that CPU is idle most of the times, yet psensors show this output

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +59.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I am only using firefox Quantum 67.0 with around 20 tabs. I need to know what is the issue which is slowing down the system. Is it overheating, or excess CPU Usage, or will a full disk cleanup and re-installation help?

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers? If so, which version? If not, that's the problem.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: What overheating? Your sensors output shows you're at ~60°, that isn't a high temperature. Note that high and critical are shown as 100° for your CPU. Also, what do you mean by "slow"? Are you talking about how responsive the GUI is (things like moving windows etc.) or does this also affect command line operations?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes I am using nvidia 340 driver

Comment: @mandar That version is only for legacy hardware. At the time of this writing Nvidia recommends **430**. If not available in the 18.04 repository, please add the graphics drivers PPA: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @terdon , thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it next time onwards. And by slow, I mean when I use it after keeping it idle for a long time like 7-8 hours, it is very slow in terms of responsiveness. Like opening a new tab will take much longer. On command line I don't perform much operations as mostly I use it for browsing etc. Sometimes opening the unity dash will take time, sometimes opening the setting takes lot of time. Basicaly GUI responsiveness and browsing issues are of concern here.

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and include that. That sounds like a classic issue of leaving a browser open for too long and its having used up loads of memory. Both chrome and firefox have suffered from this at different times. Try simply closing your browser and reopening it. Does that fix it? And sorry, but that wasn't a suggestion, it was a request: please remove the images and replace them with actual text so that we can see what's going on in your question without having to open other tabs.

Comment: @terdon I've edited the question. Actually it becomes stable after some usage , just like I am able to use it normally now while typing. So, I'll try the closing and re-opening thing next time. Sometimes the screen also freezes(it becomes pink), i.e becomes unresponsive, that too when I'm not overdoing stuff.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia i ran the ubuntu-drivers devices command and got the following output :

`== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001140sv000017AAsd0000380Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (GeForce 820M)
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin`

Recommended driver is nvidia-340 which is already installed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia also in the link to the PPA this is mentioned : For G8x, G9x and GT2xx GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.107), but on the NVIDIA Website, it says the latest non-beta driver for linux x86_64 for GEForce 820M is  : **Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver Version 430.26**. I'm confused what to do.

Comment: Add the PPA, install 430. After adding the PPA you can open Additional Drivers and select from there.

Answer (score 2):

With 4GB of RAM, you are on the low-end of the recommended specs, as seen here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

> From 17.10 onwards the desktop uses GNOME Shell. In order to run these
>   environments the system needs a more capable graphics adapter – see
>   more here or below: ... 4096 MiB RAM (system memory) for physical
>   installs.

As noted in the comment of the other (now (un)deleted(?)) response,`free` isn't a great indication, as Linux will use all of the RAM you give it. A better idea would be to see what is using the RAM.

I would suggest using a tool like "htop" to help you track resource usage among specific applications to see if that can help you pin down areas of improvement.

Comment: Running htop is giving mostly things like multiple instances of firefox, gnome-shell, dropbox, xorg. Attaching image link here since output can't be copy-pasted : https://ibb.co/Gs9QsX7

Comment: You should sort by memory usage so that you can get a better idea of what is eating up your RAM - you can find how to sort by in the bottom bar of htop, or by exploring the man pages. As a side note, slowness isn't necessarily only due to high memory utilization, but can be due to several other factors. Gnome is not a light OS desktop environment, and your hardware is somewhat older now. It may be worthwhile to explore a distribution that utilizes a light desktop environment (which is basically all other DE's).

Comment: This is the output of htop sorted by memory usage. https://ibb.co/rdxR4m0
Mostly it is firefox all the way

Answer (score 1):

It is running slow most likely due to insufficient memory (only 1200MB seems to be available). I have often found that Firefox eats up a lot more memory than some other browsers. One fix that has worked for me in such situations is switching to Google Chrome.

Comment: No, "free" is not actual indication of free memory. This article will give you a better idea : [https://www.linuxatemyram.com/]

Comment: You're right, my bad. I missed the 'available' column which really indicates how much memory you have for other usages, which in this case does not look too bad.
I still, however, stand by my observation about switching browsers, but it is perhaps not useful here.